# How to keep the Cognos List structure?

Tags: cognos, cognos-10

I have this list with some Grouped columns and with some non grouped columns as well as some List Header and Footer.

I also have some automatic created TOTALS for some of the metrics as well as some manually created totals for some metrics.

QUESTION : I now simply need to REPLACE a metric on the report by another metric. Problem is that the list displays automatic totals for some of the metrics including the one i need to replace so i want to know if it will break (destroy) the structure of my list and will i need to recreate its structure or is there a way to replace the metric without affecting my list sttucture, therefore no need to recreate my totals

Regards !

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can go to the query for the list

In the query, find the data item

Change the expression definition to the new thing you want

Change the property for the name & label too

This way you do not have to adjust the layout